# find difference between two associative multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

I have two associative multidimensional arrays, now I want to get values which are not present in the second array (compare by both key name and type).

```
$sql = "select * from `medicine`;"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$response = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array("name" => ucfirst($row['name']), "type" => $row['type']));
}
```

Output :

> `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A2 [type] => syringe ) [1] => Array
>   ( [name] => A3 [type] => syringe ) [2] => Array ( [name] => A3 [type]
>   => capsule ) [3] => Array ( [name] => A4 [type] => syringe )[4] => Array ( [name] => A5 [type] => a ) [5] => Array ( [name] => A6 [type]
>   => capsule ) )`

```
$s = "select * from `doctor_medicine` where `email` = '$email';";   
$res = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$resp = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($resp, array("name" => ucfirst($row['medicine_name']),"type" => $row['type']));
}
```

Output :

> `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A2 [type] => syringe ) [1] => Array
>   ( [name] => A3 [type] => capsule ) [2] => Array ( [name] => A4 [type]
>   => syringe ) )`

I don't know how to find difference
Result :

> `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => A3 [type] => capsule ) [4] => Array
>   ( [name] => A5 [type] => a ) [5] => Array ( [name] => A6 [type] =>
>   capsule ) )`

Comment: Better you should post your code and output instead of just screenshot.

Comment: maybe `array_diff()` is all you need?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `array_diff_assoc()`
for example:

```
<?php
$a = array(
   "who" => "you", 
   "what" => "thing", 
   "where" => "place",
   "when" => "hour"
);

$b = array(
   "when" => "time", 
   "where" => "place", 
   "who" => "you",
   "what" => "thing"
);

$c = array_diff_assoc($a, $b);
print_r ($c);
?>
```

You can try above code [here](https://eval.in/833097)

And you can use `array_intersect()` for find resemblance.for example:

```
<?php
$a = array(
  "who" => "you", 
  "what" => "thing", 
  "where" => "place",
  "when" => "hour"
);
$b = array(
  "when" => "time", 
  "where" => "place", 
  "who" => "you",
  "what" => "thing"
);
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
print_r ($c);
?>
```

You can try above code [here](https://eval.in/833100)